# Finding min/max of moving window in O(log(n))

Tags: scala, treemap

I have this school assignment where I have to create a max/min finder from a moving window in O(log(n)). Assignment gives a hint to use java class java.util.TreeMap or queues in the implementation. So far, I have only been able to create working code that functions in O(n) using queues. Under is what I have done so far with treeMap but I have problems understanding the treeMap class. I just don't seems to find correct tools to use. Now it removes the biggest value not the earliest one. I tried to also pair the values with indexes but I then I wasn't able to compare the values in order to find the biggest value.

```
import java.util.TreeMap._

class FastMaxMin[A <% Ordered[A]](windowSize: Int) {
   val tree = new java.util.TreeMap[A,A]()
   var size = 0

   /**
   * Every apply should insert new value to the moving window, removes the earliest 
   * one and returns (min, max) of the current window.
   */

   def insert(value: A): (A, A) = {
      if(size = windowSize){
        tree.pollLastEntry()
        size-=1 
      }
      tree.put(value, value)
      size+=1
      (tree.firstKey(), tree.lastKey()
   }
}
```

If anyone could even nudge me forward with this thing I would be pleased.

Answer (score 1):

Have you [read](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) the `TreeMap` documentation?

> A Red-Black tree based NavigableMap implementation. The map is sorted according to the natural ordering of its keys, or by a Comparator provided at map creation time, depending on which constructor is used.
>
> This implementation provides guaranteed log(n) time cost for the containsKey, get, put and remove operations. Algorithms are adaptations of those in Cormen, Leiserson, and Rivest's Introduction to Algorithms.

So it is a sorted data structure. Although it doesn't say, you can probably assume that `firstKey` and `lastKey` are either constant time or O(log N), so calling the four of `put`, `firstKey`, `lastKey`, and `remove` give you O(log N) bound.

In order for this to work, you need to give the constructor of the tree map a hint as how the keys are sorted. You are having a bit of a mismatch here between Scala, where you ask for an implicit conversion parameter `A => Ordered[A]`, and the `TreeMap` constructor (which has no knowledge of this parameter), so it's "using the natural ordering of its keys", which may or may not be correct in your case.

If you want to make sure the keys are correctly sorted, you should either ensure that `A <: Comparable`, or give an explicit `Comparator`.

Since you store the same value as key and value, and you never use the value, you could make it also a `TreeMap[A, Unit]`, or indeed a `TreeSet`. You could also swap the `java.util.TreeMap` for a proper Scala collection, like `collection.mutable.SortedSet`. This ensures ordering by way of an instance of `Ordering[A]` (a so-called type class). It has the same methods `firstKey` and `lastKey`.

---

Hint: To remove the oldest value as the window slides, there is nothing wrong with maintaining a second data structure that has fast addition and removal of the first or last element. Your question also mentions this data structure.

Comment: I understand the concept of that Comparator but I don't understand how I implement it (I only get errors)

Comment: I made it almost work. Problem is that if you add same value twice it doesn't count it as 2 instances :(

Comment: @Jezzie You could use a `Map[A, Int]` then as a multi-set.

Comment: @Jezzie If you are getting errors, perhaps amend the question with the concrete problem. Note, you can still go the Java way with `A <: Comparable`. What you need to solve is combine a set/map with a sequential structure to remove the oldest elements.